# how to list every element of storage files in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-storage

How to list every element of storage files in firebase.

In the official documentation there is no any word, about this. 
https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

I want to iterate storage files:
I use pyrebase, my code:

```
firebase   =   pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db         =   firebase.database()
storage    =   firebase.storage()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I thought I'd answer as I was looking for an answer to this same question

```
storage = firebase.storage()
files = storage.list_files()
for file in files:
    print(storage.child(file.name).get_url(None))
```