# List all the files of firebase storage by pyrebase?

Tags: python, storage, pyrebase

I would like to get the list of firebase storage by pyrebase(Python)

[how to list every element of storage files in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663687/how-to-list-every-element-of-storage-files-in-firebase)

Above link explain about it.
But when I try to use this code, Python show this error message.

```
files = storage.list_files()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 439, in list_files
    return self.bucket.list_blobs()
AttributeError: 'Storage' object has no attribute 'bucket'
```

Code :

```
storage = firebase.storage()
files = storage.list_files()
for file in files:
    print(storage.child(file.name).get_url(None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could succeed this.

In conifg, I added

"serviceAccount": "******.json"

****.json :  serviceAccount file

Please refer below URL how can you download serviceAccount
[Firebase Permission Denied with Pyrebase library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082171/firebase-permission-denied-with-pyrebase-library?rq=1)